# VK Android SDK Вложенные запросы выполняются вразнобой

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-asynctask, android-vksdk

Пытаюсь последовательно получать данные из рекламного кабинета. Вначале все доступные мне рекламные кабинеты:

```
  VK.execute(adsService.adsGetAccounts(), new VKApiCallback<List<AdsAccount>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(List<AdsAccount> adsAccounts) {
                        getClientsIds(adsAccounts);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void fail(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    }
                });
```

Затем из всех этих кабинетов достаю аккаунты всех клиентов:

```
 private void getClientsIds(List<AdsAccount> adsAccounts) {
        for (AdsAccount account :
                adsAccounts) {

            VK.execute(adsService.adsGetClients(account.getAccountId()), new VKApiCallback<List<AdsClient>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<AdsClient> adsClients) {
                   getCampaignsIds(account, adsClients);
                }

                @Override
                public void fail(@NonNull Exception e) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

А из них в свою очередь достаю все возможные кампании, при этом вывожу в текстовое поле имя клиента, а потом название всех его кампаний:

```
private void getCampaignsIds(AdsAccount account, List<AdsClient> adsClients) {
        textView.append(account.getAccountName() + "\n");
        for (AdsClient client :
                adsClients) {
            VK.execute(adsService.adsGetCampaigns(account.getAccountId(), client.getId(), null, null, null), new VKApiCallback<List<AdsCampaign>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<AdsCampaign> adsCampaigns) {
                    for (AdsCampaign campaign :
                            adsCampaigns) {
                        textView.append(campaign.getName() + " \n");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void fail(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Так вот, дело в том, что запросы то в итоге выполняются, но как-то очень медленно, урывками и вразнобой. Структуры, которую я ожидал, вроде

```
    Имя клиента 1
      Кампания 1
      Кампания 2
    Имя клиента 2
      Кампания 3
      Кампания 4
```

не получается.

Выходит что-то скорее такое:

```
    Имя клиента 1
    Имя клиента 2
    Кампания 1
    Кампания 2 
    Кампания 3
    Кампания 4
    Имя клиента 3
    Кампания 5
    Кампания 6
```

Можно ли делать запросы как-то пакетно, и так, чтобы сохранялся порядок? Метод для пакетного создания, описанный в документации, у меня не получается найти, возможно его поменяли в новых версиях.

Еще я думал, что может нужно использовать многопоточность, но я с ней еще не очень хорошо разобрался, и с нахрапа реализовать не получилось.

Comment: все выполняется правильно сейчас, иначе будет очень долго сеть отрабатывать, это неэффективно. В чем для Вас проблема от того, что запросы не в том порядке идут?

Comment: Просто не работайте сразу со строкой, работайте со списками и объектами. Создайте класс `ClientWithCompanies`, с полями для 1 клиента и списка кампаний, сохраняйте данные по клиентам в объект этого класса, а потом из списка объектов `ClientWithCompanies` формируйте строку, когда все запросы сработали

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov
Понял, хорошая идея, а как понять, когда все запросы сработали? И все-таки, нет ли в нынешней версии SDK аналога `VKBatchRequest`, не нахожу его, или от него отказались?

Comment: По SDK не подскажу - с VK только баловался года два назад, реально работать с ним не доводилось. А определить, прошли ли все запросы, можно заранее посчитав, сколько запросов будет. Получится какое-то число. Каждый раз, как один из запросов завершился (успехом или ошибкой), уменьшаем это число на 1.  Когда число достигло нуля можно считать, что все запросы прошли и выводить инфу на экран.